# Form partial in RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I need to make a form that I can show on every page of my Refinery site. I know about

```
rails g refinery:form
```

and in fact, have already used that. I'm just wondering how to turn the generated view (located in /vendor/extensions) into a partial that I can use across the whole site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Nope. Explored it pretty thoroughly but didn't find an answer, so I switched to Comfortable Mexican Sofa, which is another Rails CMS. You should look it up! (Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with Comfortable Mexican Sofa.)

Comment: OK. I think the answer is effectively unrelated to Refinery. It's a general Rails question about how to make a partial from an Engine view. I also have a feeling I've found the answer before for something I was trying to do, but I don't recall where! I'll update this if I spot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IGNIS, it should just work!

Using RefineryCMS -- I have an extension at `vendor/extensions/notices`.

In there is a partial `app/views/custom/_displayLatestNotices.html.erb` like:

```
<ul id="notices">
  <% Refinery::Notices::Notice.each do |notice| %>
     <li><h3><%= notice.title %></h3>
         <p><%= notice.body %></p>
     </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And I can show that from the main site code like:

```
<% content_for :body do %>
  <%= render( :partial => "custom/displayLatestNotices" ) %>
<% end %>
```

So, in your generated form extension for "widget" you will probably have something like: `app/views/refinery/widgets/widgets/new.html.erb`.

I would refactor that into two files, with the form itself in: `app/views/refinery/widgets/widgets/_new_widget_form.html.erb`.
In your `new.html.erb` you probably want to include this form partial -- and you should be able to include it elsewhere via:
`<%= render( :partial => "refinery/widgets/widgets/_new_widget_form" ) %>`
or possibly even just:
`<%= render( :partial => "_new_widget_form" ) %>`

Comment: Thank you! You're a hero! Sorry about the acceptance delay.